# Can a large number of small matrices be multiplied quickly?

Tags: matrices, algorithms

I know two large matrices can be multiplied faster than one would naively expect.  A large number of the same matrix can be multiplied quickly using repeated squaring.  But what about a large number of small matrices?  Specifically, can I find the product of one million two by two matrices all the entries of which are positive integers less than five quickly (or faster than expected)?

Comment: The mathematical interpretation of this question was answered by AlgorithmsX, and assuming that there is no mathematical/algorithmical "trick", then this might turn out to be a (interesting) *programming* problem. With some additional background information, it might be well suited for stackoverflow. (It at least sounds like something that could nicely be executed *in parallel*, as a fairly trivial [reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)), but that's just an initial idea)

Comment: If you did this in a straightforward way in a language like C I bet it'd take less than a second. Is that not fast enough?

Comment: @littleO: Not sure about C, but if I use PARI/gp and enter: a=[1,2;3,4]; b=a; for(i=1,999999,b=b*a); I have to wait 16 min, 12,311ms.  This doesn't pass the coffee test.  Otoh the statement: b=a^1000000; executes in 331 ms.  and gives the exact integer result with log(b[1,1])=1681251.2  I'd be very happy with something that gives exact results in less than a minute and if C does this I may have to learn a new trick.

Comment: @Marco13:  Thanks for this, it is interesting.  I may try stackoverflow.

Comment: @littleO As pointed out [in a comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2074131/can-a-large-number-of-small-matrices-be-multiplied-quickly?noredirect=1#comment4260939_2074677), there may be a caveat here: If this is supposed to be done in integer arithmetic, and (which is likely) the resulting values are larger than a `long`, then doing this in C may involve a "large number library". Of course, conceptually, it would still be "simple", but still *far* more difficult (and *far* less efficient!) than if it was done with `float`...

Comment: @Marco13 That's a good point, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been looking around, and it doesn't really look like it. The problems come from being unable to rearrange the matrices due to their lack of communitivity and all the better matrix multiplication algorithms work better on larger matrices than on smaller matrices.

Your best bet would be to run a preliminary search for any patterns like $ABABABABABABABAB$, which can be reduced down to $(AB)^8$, whicy can be calculated quickly by using methods like exponentiation by squaring. Even searching for a pattern seems a little hard. You'll probably still take around a million calculations or so.